# My cascaded dropdowns losing selected values after submit in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I keep selected values for both dropdown after submit action?

In my scenarios, my cascaded dropdown is populating from partial view. I'm new to ASP.NET Core MVC. Let me know if you want more clarifications.

My view:

```
<form asp-controller="Recommendation" asp-action="SubmitData" method="post">
    <select id="States" class="form-control selectpicker" asp-for="StateID" asp- 
            items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.StateList,"StateID","State"))"
            placeholder="Select Categories"                                          
                 onchange="console.log($(this).children(':selected').length)">
    </select>              
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityID, new SelectList(""), new {@class="select2 
                  form-control", @style = "width: 100%" })            
    <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Submit</button>           
 </form>
```

`onChange` function on first dropdown to call 2nd one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#States").change(function () {
                    var StateID = $(this).val();
                    /*debugger;*/
                    $("#CityID").empty();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Get",
                        url: "/Recommendation/GetCityList?iStateID=" + StateID,  
                        contentType: "html",
                        success: function (response) {
                            $("#CityID").append(response);                     
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        }
                    })
                })
            });
</script>
```

Partial View for Child dropdown

```
<option value="">Select City</option>
        @if (ViewBag.CityOptions != null)
        {
            foreach(var item in ViewBag.CityOptions)                        
            {
                <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
            }
        }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult IndexGet()         
{   // From where I get  values.
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        StateList = gateway.SelectList();
        StateList.Insert(0, new Model { StateID = 0, State = "Select State" });          
        ViewBag.StateList = StateList;                
        return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult SubmitData(RecommendModel recommendModel)       
{  // Submit form method and I used  RedirectToAction for calling view again.
        {            
        }            

        return RedirectToAction("IndexGet", "Recommendation");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetCityList(long iStateID)     
{  // For partial call
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        MCAlist = entity.GetCityList(iStateID);
        ViewBag.CityOptions = new SelectList(MCAlist,"MCAID","MCA");      
        return PartialView("_CityOptionPartial");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe you are using the bootstrap-select plugin.  You can try adding `$(this).selectpicker('refresh');` at the top of your change event.